# Prove that if $\mathrm{gr}(A)$ is Noetherian without zero-divisors, then so is $A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, noetherian, graded-rings, filtrations

> Let $A$ be a filtered commutative algebra and $\mathrm{gr}(A)$ the associated graded algebra.
> Prove that if $\mathrm{gr}(A)$ is Noetherian without zero-divisors, then so is $A$.

Associated graded algebra is defined as $\mathrm{gr}(A)=\bigoplus F_i/F_{i-1}$  where $F_i$ is in filter.
Let $I $  be an ideal in $A$, then I want to construct some ideal in $\mathrm{gr}(A)$ from $I$. My idea is $I'=\bigoplus (I\cap F_i)/F_{i-1}$. I am not sure it is an ideal in $\mathrm{gr}(A)$. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Are you assuming $A$ is commutative?

Comment: hint for the Noetherian part: can you realize $A$ as a quotient ring of $\operatorname{gr}A$?

hint for the zero-divisors part: can you realize $A$ as a subring of $\operatorname{gr}A$?

Comment: @leibnewtz Yes, assume $A$ commutative.